# Gridsome Build - ReferenceError: self is not defined

Tags: javascript, static-site, gridsome

I am trying to build a gridsome project that is importing a web worker js file, the issue I believe comes with the use of self and webpack.

Has any had any experience on how to setup Gridsome so that I can successfully build this project with the web worker js file.

### Steps to reproduce

```
import webWorker from '!file-loader!../webworker'

class BlobColor extends Sketch {
  init() {
    this.worker = new Worker(webWorker)
```

### Actual result

When running Gridsome build in the terminal I receive the following error ReferenceError: self is not defined

### Environment

Gridsome 0.7.14